# How to make Python regex extract working?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a pandas dataFrame with in one of the columns (`df['data']`) the following data:

```
[{'validFrom': '2009-02-16', 'validTo': None, 'country': ['NL', 'BE', 'US'],
'model': ['Free']}]
```

I tried to extract the different values using regex:

```
df.['data'].str.extract(r"\'validFrom\': \'(.*?)\',")
```

When I test this in a online regex tester it works, but when I try it in my script it returns `NaN`

I basically want to extract the values for all fields (validFrom, validTo, country and model).

Example dataframe, the `[..]` equals the above mentioned data.

```
|----------------|-------------|-------------|------------------|
|      code      |     name    |      type   |     data         |
|----------------|-------------|-------------|------------------|
|      003       |     WMG     |      other  |      [..]        |
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show an example on how the dataframe looks like? It looks like you have a dict in the df? Not a string?

Comment: You are trying to apply a regex to a dictionary ?

Comment: @LeoE i've added the table, wasn't sure how to format it. For now the dataframe is just 1 row

Comment: The important part is missing... What exactly is `'data'`? Is it a dict or a string?

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the other question. I didn't consider it as a dictionary. By using `json_normalize` I found a solution :)